# how would I test if a components prop is equal to another prop function?

Tags: reactjs, testing, components, enzyme

I have a component with a prop calling a prop function passing a value. 
How do I write a test using enzyme for the same?

```
<LabeledInput
                name='zip'
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
                onBlur={() => this.props.onBlur('zip')}
              />
beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      onChange: sinon.spy(),
      onBlur: sinon.spy(),
    };
    wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<ContactCard {...props}/>);
  });
it('should call onChange prop', () => {
    const labeledInputs = wrapper.find(LabeledInput);
    let zipInput = labeledInputs.filterWhere(input => input.props().name === 'zip');
    expect(zipInput.props().onChange).to.equal(props.onChange);
  });

  it('should onBlur prop ', () => {
    const labeledInputs = wrapper.find(LabeledInput);
    let zipInput = labeledInputs.filterWhere(input => input.props().name === 'zip');
    expect(zipInput.props().onBlur).to.equal(props.onBlur);
  });
```

first one (onChange test)works.
Second one gives error "AssertionError: expected [Function: onBlur] to equal [Function: proxy]"

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing 2 different function reference and trying to assert it to be equal.

`onBlur={() => this.props.onBlur('zip')}` creates a new function reference which then calls to `this.props.onBlur('zip')`

In your assert you are trying to match `() => this.props.onBlur('zip') === this.props.onBlur('zip')` which will always be false.

FWIW `[Function: proxy]` is for spy function.

Possible fix, can probably look for `toHaveBeenCalled` on onBlur prop and assert using that way.

In Sinon world it seems like using one of below three:

- `expect(props.onBlur.called).to.equal(true);`
- `sinon.assert.called(props.onBlur);`
- `assert(props.onBlur.called);`

Comment: Thanks. I understand but how would I test if the onBlur prop value is props.onBlur at the end?

Comment: You can probably try to do the same way you are doing with onChange i.e. `onBlur={this.props.onBlur}` but then not sure if you really need to pass 'zip' only onBlur and not onChange.

Comment: since I'm not simulating an onBlur, or since the event is not triggered, cannot test of the prop function is called or not. I can only see the prop for this component has the parent component's prop function as value

Comment: yeah in your scenario it will always be false so this matching is wrong IMO: `expect(zipInput.props().onBlur).to.equal(props.onBlur);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simulate the blur event and check the prop function is called like this.

zipInput.props().onBlur()

expect(props.onBlur.calledWith('zip')).to.be.true;